# How to Sort a LongListSelector using CollectionViewSource

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, collectionviewsource, longlistselector

I have a `LongListSelector` that is currently being populated with images from `IsolatedStorage`. I would like be able to sort these by date in ascending or descending order. I have been referencing http://babaandthepigman.wordpress.com/2011/07/03/wp7-collectionviewsource-sorting-a-listbox/ for assistance. For some reason, I have having trouble binding the `ItemsSource` of my `LongListSelector` to the `CollectionViewSource` to implement the sort feature.

PictureRepository.cs (to load the pictures from `IsolatedStorage` when application starts)

```
#region Constants

    public const string IsolatedStoragePath = "Pictures";

    #endregion

    #region Properties

    public ObservableCollection<Picture> Pictures
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    #endregion

    #region Singleton Pattern

    private PictureRepository()
    {
        LoadAllPicturesFromIsolatedStorage();
    }

    public static readonly PictureRepository Instance = new PictureRepository();

    #endregion

    /// <summary>        
    /// Saves to local storage
    /// This method gets two parameters: the captured picture instance and the name of the pictures folder in the isolated storage
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="capturedPicture"></param>
    /// <param name="directory"></param>
    public void SaveToLocalStorage(CapturedPicture capturedPicture, string directory)
    {
        //call IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication to get an isolated storage file
        var isoFile = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
        //Call the IsolatedStorageFile.EnsureDirectory extension method located in the Common IsolatedStorageFileExtensions class to confirm that the pictures folder exists.
        isoFile.EnsureDirectory(directory);

        //Combine the pictures folder and captured picture file name and use this path to create a new file 
        string filePath = Path.Combine(directory, capturedPicture.FileName);
        using (var fileStream = isoFile.CreateFile(filePath))
        {
            using (var writer = new BinaryWriter(fileStream))
            {
                capturedPicture.Serialize(writer);
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// To load all saved pictures and add them to the pictures list page
    /// </summary>
    public CapturedPicture LoadFromLocalStorage(string fileName, string directory)
    {
        //To open the file, add a call to the IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication
        var isoFile = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();

        //Combine the directory and file name
        string filePath = Path.Combine(directory, fileName);
        //use the path to open the picture file from the isolated storage by using the IsolatedStorageFile.OpenFile method
        using (var fileStream = isoFile.OpenFile(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            //create a BinaryReader instance for deserializing the CapturedPicture instance
            using (var reader = new BinaryReader(fileStream))
            {
                var capturedPicture = new CapturedPicture();
                //create a new instance of the type CapturedPicture called CapturedPicture.Deserialize to deserialize the captured picture and return it
                capturedPicture.Deserialize(reader);
                return capturedPicture;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// To load all the pictures at start time
    /// </summary>
    private void LoadAllPicturesFromIsolatedStorage()
    {
        //add call to the IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication to open an isolated storage file
        var isoFile = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
        //Call the IsolatedStorageFile.EnsureDirectory extension method located in the Common IsolatedStorageFileExtensions class to confirm that the pictures folder exists
        isoFile.EnsureDirectory(IsolatedStoragePath);

        //Call the IsolatedStorageFile.GetFileNames using the pictures directory and *.jpg as a filter to get all saved pictures
        var pictureFiles = isoFile.GetFileNames(Path.Combine(IsolatedStoragePath, "*.jpg"));

        var pictures = new List<Picture>();

        //Iterate through all the picture files in the list and load each using the LoadFromLocalStorage you created earlier
        foreach (var pictureFile in pictureFiles)
        {
            var picture = LoadFromLocalStorage(pictureFile, IsolatedStoragePath);
            pictures.Add(picture);
        }

        Pictures = new ObservableCollection<Picture>(pictures.OrderBy(x => x.DateTaken));
    }
```

App.xaml.cs

```
public static PictureRepository PictureList
    {
        get
        {
            return PictureRepository.Instance;
        }
    }
```

MainPage.xaml

```
<phone:LongListSelector x:Name="Recent" Margin="0,0,0,72"
                                    LayoutMode="Grid" GridCellSize="108,108" 
                                    SelectionChanged="recent_SelectionChanged">
```

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
#region Fields

    public System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource Source { get; set; }

#endregion

protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        //Recent.ItemsSource = App.PictureList.Pictures;  //working, unsorted

        Source = new System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource();
        Source.Source = App.PictureList.Pictures; //Not Working
        //Need some sort of Cast to IList for LongListSelector?
        Recent.ItemsSource = Source.View as IList<??>();

        if (Settings.AscendingSort.Value)
        {
            //Recent.ItemsSource = PictureRepository.Instance.Pictures.OrderBy(x => x.DateTaken);
            //Recent.ItemsSource = App.PictureList.Pictures.OrderBy(x => x.DateTaken);
            Source.SortDescriptions.Clear();
            Source.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("Date", ListSortDirection.Ascending)); 
        }
        else
        {
            //Recent.ItemsSource = PictureRepository.Instance.Pictures.OrderByDescending(x => x.DateTaken);
            //Recent.ItemsSource = App.PictureList.Pictures.OrderByDescending(x => x.DateTaken);
            Source.SortDescriptions.Clear();
            Source.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("Date", ListSortDirection.Descending)); 

        }
    }
```

Comment: So much code, so little xaml (cvs was introduced in order to allow sorting, etc in xaml fyi, otherwise you might as well use collectionview). Any reason you're not binding like `Recent.ItemsSource = Source.View`?

Comment: Well, after setting `Source.Source = App.PictureList.Pictures;` in `MainPage.xaml.cs`'s `OnNavigatedTo` event, placing `Recent.ItemsSource = Source.View;` gives an error stating `Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.ComponentModel.ICollectionView' to 'System.Collection.IList'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)`. Not sure how to cast this properly?

Comment: I was attempting to reference http://babaandthepigman.wordpress.com/2011/07/03/wp7-collectionviewsource-sorting-a-listbox/ which uses a `ListBox` instead. It seems that the source property of `ListBox` and `LongListSelector` are not the same type. `ListBox.ItemsSource` is type `IEnumerable`, but `LongListSelector.ItemsSource` is type `IList`. Apparently `CollectionViewSource` needs to be explicitly converted to `IList`.

Comment: If you convert it to `IList` it won't be a cvs anymore, would it ^_^?  Yes, seems lls's `ItemsSource` is some sort of "independent implementation" (lls doesn't derive from `ItemsControl` for some reason)  i'll try to find a solution in a bit.

Comment: You can check these out: [phone 8 only](http://blogs.windows.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2013/05/23/windows-phone-8-xaml-longlistselector.aspx), [grouping but might be relevant](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/zh-CN/b10dd460-5820-440c-a7a1-4d33dcfa2772/longlistselector-how-to-set-up-grouping-by-category), [will probably help the most, sorts the collection itself](http://www.geekchamp.com/articles/wp7-longlistselector-in-depth--part2-data-binding-scenarios)

Comment: I am using MVVM pattern with an observable collection binded to a LongListSelector and with different sorting performed on them. It works just fine.

Comment: @GeorgeNikolaides Care to elaborate on that? How is your sorting preformed?

Comment: Yes sure. Assume `Items` is an `ObservableCollection<Pictures>` and that `Pictures` class has some field called data then you would sort by: `Items.OrderBy(pic => pic.Date)`. You can also perform thinks like `.OrderBy().ThenByDescending()` and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[How to Sort a LongListSelector in Windows Phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18815570/how-to-sort-a-longlistselector-in-windows-phone/18815761?noredirect=1#18815761) was the best and most simple solution. Slightly changed my implementation but it works great.