# How to Sort a LongListSelector in Windows Phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, sorting, windows-phone-8, longlistselector

I would like to be able to sort the data bound to my LongListSelector either in ascending or descending order. I am having trouble binding the sorted data to my LongListSelector. Originally without trying to implement a sort my solution was working, but I believe that I am missing something when sorting is involved. I have also tried [How to Sort a LongListSelector using CollectionViewSource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18709361/how-to-sort-a-longlistselector-using-collectionviewsource?noredirect=1#comment27573580_18709361) with no luck. What is the best way to sort a LongListSelector?

MainPage.xaml

```
<phone:LongListSelector x:Name="Recent" Margin="0,0,0,72"
                                    LayoutMode="Grid" GridCellSize="108,108" 
                                    SelectionChanged="recent_SelectionChanged">
```

MainPage.xaml.cs (OLD)

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    Recent.ItemsSource = App.PictureList.Pictures;  //works!

    if (Settings.AscendingSort.Value)
    {
        //Recent.ItemsSource = App.PictureList.Pictures.OrderBy(x => x.DateTaken); //Error stating Cannot implicityly convert type 'SYstem.Linq.IOrderedEnumerable to System.Collections.IList
        Recent.ItemsSource = App.PictureList.Pictures.OrderBy(x => x.DateTaken) as System.Collections.IList; //No error but nothing is displayed
    }
    else
    {
        //Recent.ItemsSource = App.PictureList.Pictures.OrderByDescending(x => x.DateTaken);
        Recent.ItemsSource = App.PictureList.Pictures.OrderByDescending(x => x.DateTaken) as System.Collections.IList;
    }
}
```

**EDIT

MainPage.xaml.cs (NEW)

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    //Recent.ItemsSource = App.PictureList.Pictures; //Works with deleting, not sorted.

    if (Settings.AscendingSort.Value)
    {
        //Recent.ItemsSource = App.PictureList.Pictures.OrderBy(x => x.DateTaken).ToList();
        //Recent.ItemsSource = new ObservableCollection<Models.Picture>(App.PictureList.Pictures.OrderBy(x => x.DateTaken));
        App.PictureList.Pictures = new ObservableCollection<Models.Picture>(App.PictureList.Pictures.OrderBy(x => x.DateTaken)); //Error 
        Recent.ItemsSource = App.PictureList.Pictures;
    }
    else
    {
        //Recent.ItemsSource = App.PictureList.Pictures.OrderByDescending(x => x.DateTaken).ToList();
        //Recent.ItemsSource = new ObservableCollection<Models.Picture>(App.PictureList.Pictures.OrderByDescending(x => x.DateTaken));
        App.PictureList.Pictures = new ObservableCollection<Models.Picture>(App.PictureList.Pictures.OrderByDescending(x => x.DateTaken)); //Error 
        Recent.ItemsSource = App.PictureList.Pictures;
    }
}
```

App.xaml.cs

```
public static PictureRepository PictureList
{
    get
    {
        return PictureRepository.Instance;
    }
}
```

PictureRepository.cs

```
#region Constants

public const string IsolatedStoragePath = "Pictures";

#endregion

#region Fields

//private readonly ObservableCollection<Picture> _pictures = new ObservableCollection<Picture>();
private ObservableCollection<Picture> _pictures = new ObservableCollection<Picture>();

#endregion

#region Properties

public ObservableCollection<Picture> Pictures
{
    //get { return _pictures; }
    get { return _pictures; }
    set { new ObservableCollection<Picture>(_pictures); }
}

#endregion

#region Singleton Pattern

private PictureRepository()
{
    LoadAllPicturesFromIsolatedStorage();
}

public static readonly PictureRepository Instance = new PictureRepository();

#endregion

/// <summary>        
/// Saves to local storage
/// This method gets two parameters: the captured picture instance and the name of the pictures folder in the isolated storage
/// </summary>
/// <param name="capturedPicture"></param>
/// <param name="directory"></param>
public void SaveToLocalStorage(CapturedPicture capturedPicture, string directory)
{
    //call IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication to get an isolated storage file
    var isoFile = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
    //Call the IsolatedStorageFile.EnsureDirectory extension method located in the Common IsolatedStorageFileExtensions class to confirm that the pictures folder exists.
    isoFile.EnsureDirectory(directory);

    //Combine the pictures folder and captured picture file name and use this path to create a new file 
    string filePath = Path.Combine(directory, capturedPicture.FileName);
    using (var fileStream = isoFile.CreateFile(filePath))
    {
        using (var writer = new BinaryWriter(fileStream))
        {
            capturedPicture.Serialize(writer);
        }
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// To load all saved pictures and add them to the pictures list page
/// </summary>
public CapturedPicture LoadFromLocalStorage(string fileName, string directory)
{
    //To open the file, add a call to the IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication
    var isoFile = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();

    //Combine the directory and file name
    string filePath = Path.Combine(directory, fileName);
    //use the path to open the picture file from the isolated storage by using the IsolatedStorageFile.OpenFile method
    using (var fileStream = isoFile.OpenFile(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    {
        //create a BinaryReader instance for deserializing the CapturedPicture instance
        using (var reader = new BinaryReader(fileStream))
        {
            var capturedPicture = new CapturedPicture();
            //create a new instance of the type CapturedPicture called CapturedPicture.Deserialize to deserialize the captured picture and return it
            capturedPicture.Deserialize(reader);
            return capturedPicture;
        }
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// To load all the pictures at start time
/// </summary>
private void LoadAllPicturesFromIsolatedStorage()
{
    //add call to the IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication to open an isolated storage file
    var isoFile = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
    //Call the IsolatedStorageFile.EnsureDirectory extension method located in the Common IsolatedStorageFileExtensions class to confirm that the pictures folder exists
    isoFile.EnsureDirectory(IsolatedStoragePath);

    //Call the IsolatedStorageFile.GetFileNames using the pictures directory and *.jpg as a filter to get all saved pictures
    var pictureFiles = isoFile.GetFileNames(Path.Combine(IsolatedStoragePath, "*.jpg"));
    //var pictureFiles = isoFile.GetFileNames(Path.Combine(IsolatedStoragePath, ""));

    //Iterate through all the picture files in the list and load each using the LoadFromLocalStorage you created earlier
    foreach (var pictureFile in pictureFiles)
    {
        var picture = LoadFromLocalStorage(pictureFile, IsolatedStoragePath);
        _pictures.Add(picture);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace 
    Recent.ItemsSource = App.PictureList.Pictures.OrderBy(x => x.DateTaken) as System.Collections.IList;

by
    Recent.ItemsSource = App.PictureList.Pictures.OrderBy(x => x.DateTaken).ToList()

When you use OrderBy it return a IEnumerable not a List so `App.PictureList.Pictures.OrderBy(x => x.DateTaken) as System.Collections.IList` would just return null

Comment: That's exactly what my problem was. Simply adding `.ToList()` was exactly what was needed. Much thanks!

Comment: Quick question, I have an option to delete an item within my LongListSelector, which deleted the item from the View immediately. However now that the `.ToList()` is added, the view is not updated immediately. Is there a workaround for this? `App.PictureList.Pictures` is actually of type `ObservableCollection`, which I am assuming is why the view was updated immediately on my original implementation.

Comment: yes the reason why the view was updated was because App.PictureList.Pictures was an ObservableCollection

Comment: To delete in your sorted collection then you will need to create a observableColection of you sorted data and delete the data from there

Comment: for example App.PictureList.Pictures=new ObservableCollection(App.PictureList.Pictures.OrderBy(x => x.DateTaken))

Comment: I did try to create the new ObservableCollectino of `App.PictureList.Pictures` which is sorted, and the view regarding sorting is updated immediately. For some reason though, the deleting still only shows when the application is restarted. I updated my solution above to reflect my changes.

Comment: The problem is that App.PictureList.Pictures still contain the previous observable collection and not the new one, when you delete the item you need to delete from the new observable collection, that's why i was reassigning App.PictureList.Pictures. If you don't want to do that then you will need to create another property to hold the sorted list and remove the item from that list too

Comment: Oh ok I see. I am getting an error on `App.PictureList.Pictures = new ObservableCollection<Models.Picture>(App.PictureList.Pictures.OrderBy(x => x.DateTaken));` saying that `Property or indexer 'TestApp.Models.PictureRepository.Pictures' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only`. It seems like your first suggestion is the most simple to implement, I would like to give it a try. I was placing this in my `NavigatedTo` event.

Comment: I tried playing around with `get` and `set` (which I am very new to) in `PictureRepository.cs` when setting `public ObservableCollection<Picture> Pictures{ get { return _pictures; } }` but I am having no luck. I tried `public ObservableCollection<Picture> Pictures{ get { return _pictures; }
            set{ new ObservableCollection<Picture>(_pictures); } }` which allowed for me to delete an image and see it instantly removed in the view, but the sort feature doesn't work?

Comment: Here is the set you should use:
public ObservableCollection<Picture> Pictures
    {
        get { return _pictures; }
        set{ _pictures=value; }
    }